# Setting the Azure Trace logging switch - why in 2 places and not 1?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

While trying to figure out how to get log information for an Azure Web/Worker role, lots of posts suggest that I need to set my configuration settings in -two- places.

#### 1 Configure .config file

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="logLevel" value="2" />
    </switches>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

#### 2. Programatically (ie. OnStart method)

```
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Warning;
DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);
```

I don't understand why everyone are suggesting that we have to define the logging filter level **twice**?

Shouldn't the configuration file be sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 1st one, you're telling your application (website etc.) what kind of trace listener you would like to use. Or in other words, when you write something like `Trace.WriteLine("Something")`, who should listen to that message.

While in the 2nd place, you're telling the diagnostics monitor engine running in your VM what to do with the tracing data sent to it.

For example, in your code (OnStart method) you have configured:

> config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Warning;

What that means is that diagnostics monitor engine will only accept trace messages with log level `Warning` or above i.e. only those messages will be considered for transferring into storage. So even if you're writing `Trace.Information("Something")` in your code, that will be ignored by the diagnostics monitor.

Another thing you do in your code is telling the diagnostics engine what to do with the diagnostics data it has collected. Some of the other things you configure there are:

- Buffer Quota - How much data should be held in the buffer before it gets rolled over.
- Transfer to Storage - How frequently you would like to transfer the data to Windows Azure Storage.

Comment: Hi @gaurav! What about the `<switches>` section? Isn't that the part that is 'repeated' twice?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Not really. The one in the code specifies which kind of logs will be transferred to storage by diagnostics engine. `switch` statement in config file will decide whether or not listener should listen for a particular trace message (I think).

Comment: So if the `<switches>` say: log info and above ... and then the code says .. move any info and above to storage .. that's repeating. (unless I mis-understood you)

Comment: With the `<switches>`, you're telling that diagnostics trace listener to listen to all trace entries specified there however with the code you're telling which information should be persisted in the storage. So it may very well be possible that you're collecting everything in your application (through the configuration) however only persisting certain log types in storage (through the code). Now one could argue that the same can be done in the config itself and if you look in context of just tracing it may be right however diagnostics module in Azure encompasses other things as well. (Contd.)

Comment: Diagnostics module provides you one stop shop for entire diagnostics configuration from event logs, performance counters, IIS logs etc. So in just one place you could configure all diagnostics information you would need to collect instead of spreading things out or doing them on your own.

Comment: Ok. so if i just use the `<switches>` setting, this will then say 'trace listening, return all trace entries that are a 3, 2 or 1'. Then, using azure's default settings and -no- extra added code, this will just persist all the data retrieved from the trace listener ... which in this case is a 3, 2 or 1 (trace level). Does that sound correct?

Comment: I think this should work based on the assumption that the default value for `ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter` is `Undefined` which would transfer all the data. However I would do the other way around -- i.e. not specify the `<switches>` element in my config file and have the application return all trace entries and the configure the code to transfer selected log types to storage. The reason being you could change the diagnostics configuration on the fly without redeploying the code however to change the settings in config file to take effect you would need to redeploy your code.

Comment: "you could change the diagnostics configuration on the fly without redeploying the code " <-- rly? link?

Comment: This link should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432992.aspx. Also if you're using latest SDK, you may want to check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn186185.aspx. HTH.

Comment: Love it! Thanks!! Everything has been answered. Cheers for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

@Gaurav Mantri 's answer probably touches exactly what you needed.
However,

> Shouldn't the configuration file be sufficient?

I am not sure what you mean by "sufficient".
Azure Cloud services are already predefined with default values for the DiagnosticsMontiro, and therefor you don't HAVE to add those code lines.

Actually, since almost everything in Azure configurations can be controlled from outside the application, it is also preferred not to change configurations in code.

The following is taken from [MSDN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/):

> The Windows Azure SDK gives you the ability to configure Diagnostics using an XML configuration file (diagnostics.wadcfg) instead of programmatically configuring diagnostics in the OnStart method of your role. 
> This approach has several advantages over writing code:
>
> 1. Diagnostics starts before the OnStart method is called, so errors in start-up tasks can be caught and logged.
> 2. Any changes made to the configuration at run time will remain after a restart.
> 3. Diagnostics configuration changes do not require the code to be rebuilt.
> 4. You can automatically start the diagnostics monitor in a specific configuration without needing      additional code (which might cause an exception that would prevent your role from starting).